# In WebProtege, how do I reference a subclass in a property?

Tags: owl, protege

Have class with some subclasses:

```
Name
- FirstName
- MiddleName
- LastName
```

Have class with Name as a property:

```
Borrower  
has Address
has Name
```

Want to create the following class with relationship:

```
Title
has Borrower > Name
```

How do I construct the "Borrower > Name" property?

Comment: I don't know what `has Borrower > Name` means. What is the meaning of `>` ? Moreover, classes do not "have" properties in OWL, that is just a wrong statement. Instead, individuals of a class can have properties.

Comment: In general, you should start with a "better" syntax in your statements. Is `has` a property in your ontology? If so, then it would be `Borrower SubClassOf has some Name`. That said, I also don't see why one would use classes for things like names instead of data properties.

Comment: You seem to approaching this from an object orientation perspective. I have written about the translation from UML to OWL [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/uml-vs-owl/).

Comment: A Title needs a Borrower name and a Co-borrower name.  I would prefer not to create an subclass for Borrower and Co-Borrower named Borrower Name and Co-borrower Name. Instead I would like to know if OWL/Protege has a  subclass notation - like dot notation - Borrower.Name. Or if there is a dif suggested way to do it.

Comment: I don't understand your example, there is no dot notation in OWL nor RDF. You clearly have to introduce relationships aka. properties in order to express relations between individuals. You should read one more time about OWL and what OWL is capable of and what not

Comment: @AKSW I have read documentation. I've looked at the pizza, wine and other examples. I've read what literature I can find. In the case of ontologies the lit is crap. If you have a suggestion please write an answer. If all you can do is criticize the question I have I suggest you don't try to answer if you are going to be upset with new people's lack of understanding of a subject. That is why we are here on SO...

Comment: @aksw If you will notice I thought I was creating a relationship. I have "has Borrower > Name" That is a property. But to me that looks clumsy and if there is no way to uniquely ID sub-classes means that I need to create a ton of extra classes with unique names instead of being able to use the class hierarchy to point them. If that is the case then OWL is horribly inefficient to me but I'll deal with and create a ton of uniquely named classes so the properties can know which is which.